# hdiutil: create failed - Operation timed out

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility, smb, hdiutil

I am trying to create a Backup.dmg disk image in a folder on an SMB file system.

1. Using Disk Utility
2. Using hdiutil

   - `hdiutil create -size 4t -fs APFS -volname backup Backup.dmg`

Both operations start, but after a few minutes, they always fail with

```
create failed - Operation timed out
```

It fails the same way when trying to create an image on a USB-attached disk drive.

I recall doing this over a year ago on the same Windows box and sharing SMB folders with no problems.

Chat GPT has many options but nothing useful. Google search shows other people with the same problem but not many good solutions.

Does anyone have any insight into what is going on here?

---

*Getting some more insight here from Carbon Copy Cloner...*

Some SMB volumes can't support macOS sparse disk images

We have received several reports that macOS is unable to create disk images on SMB volumes hosted by various NAS devices. If you attempt to create the disk image in Disk Utility (for example), Disk Utility reports an "RPC Error". After months of investigation, we have concluded that macOS Catalina has more stringent requirements for sparse disk images than previous OSes.

Solution: Several users have reported that [adjusting the SMB configuration on the NAS to support Time Machine](https://kirb.me/2018/03/24/using-samba-as-a-time-machine-network-server.html) can resolve the problem. Time Machine also uses sparse disk images on NAS volumes, so its requirements for the NAS file sharing service would be the same as those required for generic sparse disk image support.

Workaround A: Several users are reporting that connecting to the network volume via AFP rather than SMB resolved the problem:

1. Eject the NAS volume if it's currently mounted
2. Choose "Connect to Server" from the Finder's Go menu
3. Type in "afp://{server address}" to connect to the NAS volume via AFP
4. Choose "New disk image..." from CCC's Destination selector and specify a new disk image on the AFP-mounted NAS volume

Workaround B: If connecting to your NAS volume via AFP is not an option, then you can back up user data (e.g. your home folder) directly to the NAS volume (i.e. don't use a disk image). We also recommend disabling support for extended attributes (via the Advanced Settings).

---

*I still have not solved the issue... still researching...*

Comment: Vary the size argument around the common boundaries (e.g. 2g and 4g). My first guess is that the filesystem has limits far less than 4 terabytes. I believe SMB 2.0 has a file size limit of 4G.

Comment: The `hdiutil create -size 4t -fs APFS -volname backup Backup.dmg` does not does not specify the creation of a spare or sparse bundle image. Instead, you are asking for the creation of a `Backup.dmg` image file of at least 4 TB in size. I would expect there would be issues with the request of the creation of a file of such a large size.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after watching the YouTube video [how to make Time Machine backup on windows shared drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0IJ4OWCYSc) I was able to get this working.

1. In Disk Utility, we can't use APFS, we have to create a disk image with HFS (MacOS Extended)

   - I recommend using sparsebundle
2. After creating `Backup.sparsebundle` and mounting it I had to use tmutil

   - `sudo tmutil setdestination /Volumes/Backup`

Finally, it worked, and I can see the Backup image in Time Machine.

Apple has decided that you cannot create an APFS file system on an SMB share unless the SMB declares the share to be for Time Machine, which you cannot do in Windows.

Sadly, the diagnostics around this are in no way helpful, forcing us to go into DevOps hacker mode. Apple did not need to make this so difficult, and I suggest they did this intentionally to prevent people from doing this.